# Translation of C# to F#

Tags: f#, member, c#-to-f#

How can I translate the following C# code to F#?

```
public Autodesk.Revit.UI.Result OnStartup(UIControlledApplication application)
{
   return Result.Succeeded;
}

public Autodesk.Revit.UI.Result OnShutdown(UIControlledApplication application)
{
    return Result.Succeeded;
}
```

Comment: In general, not by asking on Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information on how to ask a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would just convert these to members:

```
member __.OnStartup (application : UIControlledApplication) =
    Result.Succeeded

member __.OnShutdown (application : UIControlledApplication) =
    Result.Succeeded
```

Comment: Thank you very much Reed